# Determine Email Address of an AD Security Group

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

In AD here at work, we have some security groups that are mail enabled.  I am using the  System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace like so:

```
        List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();            
        using (PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, userinfo[0]))
        using (UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, username))
        {

            if (user != null)
            {
                PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

                int totalGroupCounter = 0;
                StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                List<GroupPrincipal> securityGroups = new List<GroupPrincipal>();
                List<GroupPrincipal> distributionGroups = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

                foreach (Principal group in groups)
                {
                    totalGroupCounter++;

                    if (((GroupPrincipal)group).IsSecurityGroup.Value)                        
                        securityGroups.Add((GroupPrincipal)group);                        
                    else                        
                        distributionGroups.Add((GroupPrincipal)group);                        
                }                
            }
        }
```

Armed with this info, what's the correct way to find the group's email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider marc_s an expert on active directory topics, but, I too had a security group that had an e-mail address associated with it.  Here is how I was able to fetch the e-mail from it:

```
private void GetGroupEmail() {
    using (var searcher = new DirectorySearcher()) {
        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=group))";
        searcher.SearchRoot = entry;
        searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");

        foreach (SearchResult sr in searcher.FindAll()) {
            var email = GetSearchResultProperty(sr, "mail");
        }
    }
}

private string GetSearchResultProperty(SearchResult sr, string propertyName) {
    var property = sr.Properties[propertyName];

    if (property != null && property.Count > 0) {
        return (string)property[0];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The AccountManagement libraries limit which properties you can access. If you want to get the email property for a group, you'll need to cast it back to a [`DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) object.

```
PropertyValueCollection email = ((DirectoryEntry)group.GetUnderlyingObject()).Properties["mail"];
if (email.Value != null)
{
    // Do something with email property
}
```

Comment: For those of you who stumble across this years after the fact like me, please note you need to add a reference to System.DirectoryServices

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to test for an mail-enabled group is to read the proxyAddresses and test for any entry witch starts with "smtp:". Only test for the email-field is not sufficient. Extend the GroupPrincipal like

```
public bool IsMailEnabled
        {
            get
            {
                var proxyAddresses = ExtensionGet("proxyAddresses");
                if (proxyAddresses == null)
                    return false;

                if (proxyAddresses.Length == 0)
                    return false;

                try
                {
                    List<string> proxyAddressesStringList = proxyAddresses.Cast<string>().ToList();
                    if (proxyAddressesStringList.Where(x => x.StartsWith("smtp:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)).Count() > 0)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
```